# How do strings work in VB

Tags: vbscript

I am currently reworking an Intranet Website using Active Directory, and the ancient developer did everything in VB, I am now developing it in C# and a bunch of recent technologies. So I am going through his code for a few functionalities I'm having a hard time with (I did a quick overview of VB to see how it works globally) and I don't understand how strings work here.

For example, there is the following declaration:

```
Dim sGroups, oGroup
sGroups=activeDirectoryUserObject.memberOf //Returns groups that user belongs to
set oGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & sGroups)
For j = 0 To UBound(sGroups)
    Set oGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & sGroups(j)) //Here!!
```

What is `sGroups(j)`? To me `sGroups` is a string not an array, so what's going on here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what type does `activeDirectoryUserObject.memberOf` return? sGroups is of that type.

Comment: This is not .NET code so hard to guess.  memberOf is a "multi-valued attribute", so surely an array.  The groups that the user belongs to, more than one.  VB allows indexed properties, C# doesn't, ought to be covered by Principal.GetGroups() in .NET.  The first assignment is just nonsense, the For-loop ought to provide the real assignment.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, I was sure it was a string ... Can't verify my code right now I'm not at work, but there are lines in between the declaration of `oGroup` and the for loop I just didn't post it because it was not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leonard:

It appears that sGroups(j) is a string and that the (j) part is a counter.  Possible that this is being used if the user belongs to more than one group.

Sincerely,

Joe

Comment: Yes you are right about the multiple groups. The whole point of the method is to create a group tree to know all the groups a user belongs to, and then be able to make a dynamic menu according to these. So j is a counter, I guess as @Hans said, the declaration using memberOf is probably an array declaration, so then it all makes sense. Will verify tomorow

Answer (score 1):

Strings are not indexed in VBS/VBA/VB6. And the method of indexing is different in VB.NET.  So if the object is indexed, "sGroups(j)" *it's not a string*.

The obvious way to work out what sGroups is, would be to look at activeDirectoryUserObject and it's memberOf attribute.  Which you should have done, *and you should have included that code here*, so that we could see it.

If it's an externally defined object, for which you have no documentation, you can use the Typename() function or VarType function to extract the information.  Since this is a website using ASP scripting, either it's going to be a variant array, or the script is completely broken.

Either is possible, since the script fragment you have provided makes no sense by itself (see also the redefinition of oGroup with no code that uses it).

Comment: The whole difficulty here is that it is used as a string AND as an array, which is why I posted oGroups definition, because it uses sGroups as a String. It would be too long for me to test this, I think it is just a semantics issue, which is why I did not feel the need to post something testable. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: sGroups is not used as a string in your code fragment. sGroups(j), is used as a string. An array of integers is not an integer: an array of strings is not a string.

Comment: 3rd line of code : sGroups is a string. I have also checked with the developer who told me there are two cases depending on the memberOf attribute which can be a string or an array. Conclusion: sGroups is a string OR sGroups is an array depending on memberOf property.